# Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming

Tags: centos, gnome, login, crash

When trying to login into CentOS 7 either through the Gnome GUI or the login shell, I get this: [image: Error Message, right before I get booted back to login screen]

After a second, I get booted backed to the login shell, or login screen of Gnome.

I've tried booting using the 'CentOS...recovery...' option during boot up, but same thing happens.

What should I do?

Edit: basically, I'd like to know how to run systmctl (to do what the error suggested) when I can't login into my accounts.

Comment: can you get to a point (text login console?) where you can run the recommended "systemctl status kdump.service" command?

Comment: I can't run commands without logging in. And the picture above is what happens when I login with any account. Then it returns me to login screen or shell.

Comment: No text console on alt-f1?

Comment: Same thing happens in text console. After logging in, this message, then it exits back to login shell.

Comment: `sudo systemctl status kdump.service` says "kdumpctl[1643]: No memory reserved for crash kernel." for me with this error. However I have no problem logging in

Comment: I disabled kdump.service since it doesn't start anyway: `sudo systemctl disable kdump.service`. No more errors